# Silverlight Binding to parent DataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have Array of Users and array of Roles.
For each user i'am rendering list of roles.
I want to bind checkboxes to some user property.

Here is my code ( line 38 ):
https://gist.github.com/sadgb/30e2b75f2fff159bc26e#file-gistfile1-xml-L38

Why this line:

`{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}, Path=DataContext}`

...binds to Role class, not to User class?

Binding should find grid at line 21, which has DataContext of type User isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way: -
1. Give any name to your grid.
2. then do ur binding like this :

`DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Gridname,Path=DataContext}"`

Here is your edited code:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="usersService:User">
    <Grid Name="TheGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding UserId}"/>
        <telerik:RadListBox Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=users:UsersPage}, Path=RolesViewModel.Roles}" IsTextSearchEnabled="false">
            <telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="accessControlSubsystem:Role">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox
                            IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=TheGrid,Path=DataContext , Converter={StaticResource CheckBoxToSelectedArrayConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding RoleName}" Tag="{Binding RoleId}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadListBox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I guess this will solve your problem or at least give you a good start.

One more thing I noticed in your code is that you didn't specify the property name in your relative binding:

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}, Path=DataContext.PopertyName, Converter={StaticResource CheckBoxToSelectedArrayConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"  Content="{Binding RoleName}" Tag="{Binding RoleId}"
```

Comment: well. it works. Thank you. About second guess - i just need entire DataContext, so i don't need to specify PropertyName

Comment: Yes is that case it should be DataContext not IsChecked i guess

Comment: No, i have complicated converter that needs all User class as input to determine if checkbox should be checked, or not. Nvm, it doesn't matter now. Your code works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the level up one using "ancestorLevel"

{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}, AncestorLevel=1, Path=DataContext}

Oliver

Comment: modified my code this way https://gist.github.com/sadgb/ee25d928dc5124a5d4b6. Still in my converter i have value of type Role